# Find local duplicates (which follow each other) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find local duplicates and give them a unique id, directly in pandas.

**Reallife example:**

Time-ordered purchase data where a customer id occures multiple times (because he visits a shop multiple times a week), but I want to identify occasions where the customer purches multiple items at the same time.

**My current approach would look like this:**

```
def follow_ups(lst):
    lst2 = [None] + lst[:-1]
    i = 0
    l = []
    for e1, e2 in zip(lst, lst2):
        if e1 != e2:
            i += 1
        l.append(i)
    return l

follow_ups(['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
# [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# for pandas
df['out'] = follow_ups(df['test'])
```

But I have the feeling there might be a much simpler and cleaner approach in pandas which I am unable to find.

**Pandas Sample data**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'test':['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C']})
#    test
# 0     A
# 1     B
# 2     B
# 3     C
# 4     B
# 5     D
# 6     D
# 7     D
# 8     E
# 9     A
# 10    B
# 11    C

df_out = pd.DataFrame({'test':['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'out':[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
#    test  out
# 0     A    1
# 1     B    2
# 2     B    2
# 3     C    3
# 4     B    4
# 5     D    5
# 6     D    5
# 7     D    5
# 8     E    6
# 9     A    7
# 10    B    8
# 11    C    9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare whether your column test is not equal to it's shifted version, using `shift()` with `ne()`, and use `cumsum()` on that:

```
df['out'] = df['test'].ne(df['test'].shift()).cumsum()
```

Which prints:

```
df

   test  out
0     A    1
1     B    2
2     B    2
3     C    3
4     B    4
5     D    5
6     D    5
7     D    5
8     E    6
9     A    7
10    B    8
11    C    9
```